# How to split tuple into multiple columns on pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I've got a dataframe that has 1 column and thousands of rows. Each cell contains a tuple, with different values corresponding to different categories. I want to split this tuple, so that each value now has a column of its own. Any idea how I can do this?

Below is an example of the contents of one cell

```
(None, 1472743915, 20160901, 1, 1, None, 1, None, None, None, None, (not set), (not provided), True, Android, Australia, Sydney, tpgi.com.au)
```

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: I'd like to transform the above tuple into a dictionary with keys I chose

Answer (score -1):

If you have a `dataframe` with only one column, it is a `pd.Series` most likely.  You can transform it to a list of tuples and then construct a data frame from that list as such:

```
In [11]: data                                                                   
Out[11]: 
0    (None, brown, dog, 3.4)
1      (5, yellow, cat, 1.4)
dtype: object

In [12]: type(data)                                                             
Out[12]: pandas.core.series.Series

In [13]: df = pd.DataFrame(data.to_list(), columns=['id', 'color', 'type', 'weig
    ...: ht'])                                                                  

In [14]: df                                                                     
Out[14]: 
    id   color type  weight
0  NaN   brown  dog     3.4
1  5.0  yellow  cat     1.4

In [15]:
```

If you have access to the orig list of tuples, you can just call the `pd.DataFrame()` constructor on the list of tuples in the same manner.

Comment: It's not working, I guess because the type of data is 'RowIterator',